# Mathematical function to find number of leaf nodes in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

There is a unbalanced binary tree of unknown depth. The number of nodes having two child nodes is denoted by `T2`. The node having only one child is denoted by `T1` and leaf nodes are denoted by `L`. If it is given that `T1 = m` and `T2 = n` nodes then can you define a mathematical function `f(m, n)` which gives number of leaf nodes L?

For example, in the below tree total `T2` nodes are `m = 3`, and total `T1` nodes are `n = 2`. The number of leaf nodes `L = f(m,n) = 4`. Can you find a mathematical function `f(m,n)` which gives number of leaf nodes for all trees?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: `F(n, m) = m + 1` It is independent of `n`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is pretty easy. In a fully binary tree (that is, every non-leaf has 2 children) of `m` internal nodes, there are exactly `m+1` leaf nodes. Every node that has only one child can be removed, and you still have a binary tree. So, the number of leaf nodes in `L` is simply `m+1`. Or answering the question: `f(m, n) = m + 1`.

It might be useful to give an example of what I mean by "removing `T1` nodes". Consider your example. The right `5` has only one child. If we remove the `5` and put the `9` under the `2` directly, the number of leafs does not change.

If we do the same for the `9` (put the `4` directly under the `2`), we have a full binary tree, that is, all non-leafs have 2 children.

See the picture for a graphic explanation of how to remove all nodes of type `T1` **without changing the number of leaf nodes**.

[image]

All that remains is to prove that in a tree of `m` internal nodes, where every non-leaf has exactly 2 children, the number of leaf nodes is `m+1`:

Proof by induction. Induction hypothesis: `|L| = |T2|+1`

Base: the tree consists of a single node. Clearly, `|L|=1` and `|T2|=0`, so it holds.

Step: Consider a tree with a root that is not a leaf. By the assumption, it has two children, left and right. By the induction hypothesis: `|Lleft|=|T2left| + 1` and `|Lright| = |T2right| + 1`. For the total tree, we have `|T2| = |T2left| + |T2right| + 1` and `|L| = |Lleft| + |Lright|`. Therefore, `|L| = |T2left| + 1 + |T2right| + 1 = |T2| + 1`.

---

**Alternative proof**

The property can also be proved directly, without the handwaving argument of removing the `T1` nodes. Again, by induction, with the induction hypothesis `|L| = |T2| + 1`.

- **Base**: the tree is a single node, so `|L| = 1` and `|T2| = 0`.
- **Step case 1**: the tree has a root with only 1 child, `X`, then `|L| = |LX|` and `|T2| = |T2X|`, so `|L| = |T2| + 1` by the induction hypothesis.
- **Step case 2**: the tree has a root with two children, left and right. By the induction hypothesis: `|Lleft|=|T2left| + 1` and `|Lright| = |T2right| + 1`. For the total tree, we have `|T2| = |T2left| + |T2right| + 1` and `|L| = |Lleft| + |Lright|`. Therefore, `|L| = |T2left| + 1 + |T2right| + 1 = |T2| + 1`.

Therefore, `|L| = |T2| + 1` or in other words `f(m, n) = m + 1`.

Comment: Is there a proof to show that removing `T1` nodes doesn't changes L nodes? You have provided only graphical explanation for this above.

Comment: @Manav the role of a node (`T1`, `T2`, or `L`) is entirely determined by its number of children. When removing a node `t` of type `T1`, only the set of children of its parent changes. Since `t` is replaced by `child(t)`, `parent(t)` still has as many children, so its role does not change.